# freeze for more than one variable

Tags: prolog, prolog-coroutining

I tried to write a predicate that takes a list and converts it to a balanced tree. My code looks as follows:

```
/* make_tree(list, tree)
 *
 *    list: list with the elements of the tree in prefix order
 *    tree: balanced tree of the elements in the list
 * 
 */
make_tree([], empty).
make_tree([H|T], node(L, R, H)):-
    split_half(T, T1, T2),
    make_tree(T1, L),
    make_tree(T2, R).

/* split_half(list, first, second)
 * 
 *    list: list with n elements
 *    first: list with first (n // 2) elements
 *    second: list with last (n - n // 2) elements
 *
 */
split_half(L, L1, L2):-
   split_half(L, L, L1, L2).

split_half(L, [], [], L):- !.
split_half(L, [_], [], L):- !.
split_half([H|T], [_,_|Acc], [H|L1], L2):-
   split_half(T, Acc, L1, L2).
```

and this works when called like:

```
?- make_tree([1,2,3], Tree).
Tree = node(node(empty, empty, 2), node(empty, empty, 3), 1).
```

but it doesn't work when calling it in the other way, like:

```
?- make_tree(L, node(node(empty, empty, 2), node(empty, empty, 3), 1)).
false.
```

It's not really necessary, but I accepted the challenge anyway to make it work both ways. I wanted to solve this by using `freeze/2` on `split`, like `freeze(T2, split(T, T1, T2))` and this makes that `?- make_tree(L, node(node(empty, empty, 2), node(empty, empty, 3), 1)).` works, but the original idea doesn't anymore. So actually what I'm looking for is some kind of `freeze/2` that can do something like `freeze((T;T2), split(T, T1, T2))`. Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do not use cuts for such predicates.

Comment: Your code is incorrect: `make_tree(T2, L).` should read `make_tree(T2, R).`

Comment: @false I corrected it. What's wrong with the cuts? It's mainly to make the code deterministic...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you are looking for `when/2`. It is offered by both SICStus Prolog ([manual page](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002dwhen.html#mpg_002dref_002dwhen)) and SWI-Prolog ([manual page](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=when/2)).

Sample use:

```
myfreeze1(V,Goal) :-
   when(nonvar(V),Goal).

myfreeze2(V1,V2,Goal) :-
   when((nonvar(V1);nonvar(V2)),Goal).
```

Comment: Why do you use `nonvar` rather than for instance `ground`?

Comment: @MrTsjolder. I thought you wanted something akin to `freeze/2`, which delays until nonvar, not until ground. See https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002dfreeze.html

Comment: I only looked around on [swi-prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=freeze/2) and I am afraid I'm not sure whether I know well enough what the difference is between `nonvar` and `ground`... Thanks in any case!

Comment: @MrTsjolder. `nonvar(V)` succeeds if `V` is not a variable  (but an integer, or float, or atom or compound, etc.). `ground(V)` additionally demands that `V` does not contain any variables. The difference shows with compound terms.

Comment: For example, the term ```t(V)``` is non-var, but also not ground.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method without using coroutining.  The idea is to establish first a relation between the tree and the *number* of its elements which is represented by a list. Note that we first do not look at concrete elements (`_`) since we do not know their order yet. With the number of elements being fixed, we can proceed as before but without the cuts.

```
list_tree(Xs, Tree) :-
   phrase(tree_els(Tree), Xs),
   make_tree(Xs, Tree).

tree_els(empty) -->
   [].
tree_els(node(L, R, _)) -->
   [_],
   tree_els(L),
   tree_els(R).
```

This version might profit from coroutining for performance reasons. After all `tree_els/1` will succeed for all possible trees be they balanced or not.

Comment: what's with the `-->` syntax and the `phrase`? I'm sorry for asking, but I didn't learn these things.

Comment: Definite Clause Grammars, [tag:dcg]. Available in any Prolog

Comment: @MrTsjolder. Thank you for asking what `-->` and `phrase` mean